# Array in state not updating after useEffect runs in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I'm extremely new to React.js. I am trying to change a variable `recepies` which is in state using hooks. Below is my code snippet:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

const [recepies, setRecepies] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{getRecepies()}, []);

//const example = Some valid API URL


  const getRecepies = async () =>{
    const response = await fetch(example);
    const data = await response.json();

    //data.hits is an array of 10 objects
     setRecepies(data.hits);

     console.log(recepies);
    // prints nothing

  }

  return (  
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The problem is that `setRecepies` is NOT updating the `recepies` state. Why is that?`data.hits` is a valid array that has 10 objects that I'm fetching using an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recepies` is a local `const`. It will never change, and that's not what `setRecepies` is trying to do. Putting a log statement where you've put it can only ever log out what `recepies` was equal to when `getRecepies` was created.

The purposes of `setRecepies` is to tell react to rerender the component. When that second render happens, a new local `const` will be created which will get the new value. This variable is visible to anything created on that second render, not to things created on the first render. So if you want to see the new value, put your log statement in the body of the component so you can see what value it's rerendering with.

```
const [recepies, setRecepies] = useState([]);
console.log('rendering with', recepies);
```

Comment: When I try to `console.log(recepies)` outside the `getRecepies()` function,*it works* but it logs the array twice! Why is that?

Comment: Because the component renders twice. The first render has an empty array, then you fetch some data and set state, then you render again with that new data.

Comment: That makes sense, but in both cases, it logs the same array. It should've logged an empty array the first time, then another one with the info right?

Comment: Yes, it should log an empty array, and then a populated array. Which array is it rendering twice?

Comment: Its showing the populated array in both the cases. I have called `console.log(recepies)` right after the ending of the `getRecepies()` function, before the `return`

Comment: I don't know why that is.